# potential race condition in go language

Tags: go

I am not sure why the following code has the race condition, can someone give me a hint?  I think there is no potential race condition.  Thank you in advance.

```
type PossiblySafeCounter struct {
    mu sync.Mutex
    sum int
}

func (c *PossiblySafeCounter) inc() {
   c.mu.Lock();
   defer c.mu.Unlock();
   go func() {
       c.sum++
   }() 
}
func (c *PossiblySafeCounter) read() int {
    c.mu.Lock();
    defer c.mu.Unlock();
    return c.sum
 }
```

Comment: Why do you think there is one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `c.sum++` is in a goroutine that is scheduled independently of the execution of the `inc()` method. When the `inc()` method exits the `defer`ed unlock of the mutex will happen and will very likely happen at the wrong time, leading to a race condition.

As @Flimzy suggests using `atomic.AddInt32` would remove the need for a mutex at all.

two mutex based solutions are either to not increment in a goroutine:

```
func (c *PossiblySafeCounter) inc() {
   c.mu.Lock();
   defer c.mu.Unlock();
   c.sum++
}
```

or do the locking and unlocking *in* the goroutine:

```
func (c *PossiblySafeCounter) inc() {
   go func() {
       c.mu.Lock();
       defer c.mu.Unlock();
       c.sum++
   }() 
}
```

but honestly, doing any kind of goroutine doesn't make sense in this example.  Why do you need the increment to be in a goroutine?

Comment: I am not sure if we are thinking the same thing.  Right after inc unlock and right before read acquire the lock, there can be goroutine modify the sum?

Comment: The fact that the actual `c.sum++` is happening in a goroutine means that the mutex is not protecting anything to do with the increment.

Comment: A better solution would be to use [`atomic.AddInt32`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#AddInt32) so no locking is necessary.